# Prove that :$[BCA']^2+[CAB']^2+[ABC']^2=[ABC]^2$, where [•] denote the area.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given any acute angled triangle $ABC$, left points $A',B',C'$ be located as follows : $A'$ is the point where altitude from A on $BC$ meets the v outwards facing semicircle drawn on BC as diameter. Pointed $B',C'$ are located similarly .Prove that : $[BCA']^2+[CAB']^2+[ABC']^2=[ABC]^2$. Where [•] denote area of triangles.

Above is the problem. We know that the area of a triangle is $\dfrac12 \cdot \text{height} \cdot \text{base}$. But I can't proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove first [the following generalization of the Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem):

> **(1)** If $OA,OB,OC$ are three mutually perpendicular lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
> $$ [ABC]^2=[OAB]^2+[OBC]^2+[OAC]^2 .$$

then prove that in your configuration $A'B=C'B,B'A=C'A,A'C=B'C$, hence you may
conclude from the previous lemma. How to prove that $A'B=C'B$? Simple. We have:
$$ A'B^2+A'C^2 = a^2, \qquad A'B^2-A'C^2 = AB^2-AC^2 = c^2-b^2 $$
(since $BB'\perp AC$) hence $A'B^2=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2}=C'B^2$.

---

Like [Desargues' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem), this $2d$-problem is easier to prove if we consider it in $3d$!

[image]

Comment: Generalization is known as [De Gua's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem). Very nice!