# Triangles and Semicircles.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Given any acute angled triangle $ABC$, let points $X, Y, Z$ be located as follows: $X$ is
the point, where the altitude from $A$ on $BC$ meets the outward facing semicircle
on $BC$ as diameter. Points $Y$ and $Z$ are defined similarly. Prove the result:
$[BCX]^2 + [CAY]^2 + [ABZ]^2 = [ABC]^2$, where the notation $[.]$ denotes the area of the figure.

A question from pathfinder for olympiad mathematics.

My Solution attempt:[image: DIAGRAM]

using $\angle XGC = \theta=\angle XCG \implies \angle XGD=2\theta \ and \ \angle XGC=\pi - \theta 
 $

Thus we get,by cosine rule,
$XD = XC^2(a^2-XC^2)$

Now i calculated the area of the triangle $BXC$ but couldnt go any furter, kindly proceed this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that :$[BCA']^2+[CAB']^2+[ABC']^2=[ABC]^2$, where \[•\] denote the area.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937055/prove-that-bca2cab2abc2-abc2-where-denote-the-area)

Comment: @MyMolecules Some Links are missing in this.It would have been helpful if those links still existed.

Comment: Dear @MohitKumar , I edited them to working  links soon after I posted my comment. Please check again.

Comment: Thanks! It would surely help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the orthocentre of the original triangle be $H$. Observe that, $AE\cdot EC=HE\cdot BE$ since $\triangle AEB\sim \triangle HEC$.

Thus, $EY^2=AE\cdot EC=HE\cdot BE$

Hence, $[\triangle ACY]^2=\frac {1}{4} AC^2\cdot HE\cdot BE=\left(\frac{1}{2} AC\cdot HE\right)\left(\frac {1}{2}AC\cdot BE\right)=[\triangle AHC]\cdot [\triangle ABC]$

Similarly,

$[\triangle BXC]^2=[\triangle BHC]\cdot [\triangle ABC]$

$[\triangle ABZ]^2=[\triangle AHB]\cdot [\triangle ABC]$

Adding these up gives the desired result.